# Static method main in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Why is there a compilation error with the line `if (i == 0) { print(); }`? Is it because main is static, even though it is within the class of A?

```
public class A {
        private void print() { System.out.print(foo() + " "); }
        public String foo() { return "AAA"; }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
              A[] arr = { new A(), new B() };
              for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
/***/                  if (i == 0) { print(); }
}
}
}
public class B extends A {
       private void print() { System.out.println("%" + foo() + " "); }
       public String foo() { return "BBB"; }
       public void bar() { print(); }
}
```

Comment: main is static; print is not. Very basic stuff; which honestly, you shouldn't ask for; but learn from tutorials, books, etc.

Comment: Learn what `static` means: [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is a compiler error because you are trying to call the non-static method `print` from the static method `main`. And yes, `main` must be static.

You need to create an instance of `A`, and then call the print method on that instance:

```
A a = new A();
a.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

`print()` is non-static. This means that it is meant for objects of the class A. You cannot call it from `main()` because it is static, and static methods belong to the class. To call `print()`, you can do:

```
A a = new A();
a.print();
```